# Deleting rows which sum to zero in 1 column (like pairs) but some elements in other columns are different

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider a dataframe like

| product | date | value | city | reference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| y | 21-01-2020 | -16 | Paris | xji |
| x | 25-01-2020 | -16 | Munich | zyc |
| x | 01-05-2020 | 16 | Munich | dkj |
| y | 20-01-2020 | -20 | Paris | jkdl |
| z | 21-01-2020 | 30 | Munich | 212jio |
| t | 05-01-2020 | 2 | Munich | jidi1 |
| y | 21-03-2020 | 20 | Paris | reg1 |

I would like to delete rows that value cancel each other, having something like

| product | date | value | city | reference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| y | 21-01-2020 | -16 | Paris | xji |
| z | 21-01-2020 | 30 | Munich | 212jio |
| t | 05-01-2020 | 2 | Munich | jidi1 |

Answer (score 0):

We aggregate by city and by abs(value) to match transactions, then add them up and remove those matched transactions that add up to 0:

```
df2 = (df.groupby([df['city'], abs(df['value'])])
         .agg({'product':'first','city':'first', 'date':'first','value':sum, 'reference':'first'})
         .reset_index(drop = True)
)
df2.where(df2['value']!=0).dropna()
```

output:

```
    product city    date        value   reference
0   t       Munich  05-01-2020  2.0     jidi1
2   z       Munich  21-01-2020  30.0    212jio
3   y       Paris   21-01-2020  -16.0   xji
```